# Connect to Nitrous.IO MySQL server using MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, ssh, mysql-workbench, nitrousio

I'm trying connect to my Nitrous.IO MySQL server instance using MySQL Workbench on a Windows box (in other words, without port forwarding). These are the steps I've taken without success, maybe someone can point out any mistakes/potential issues?

1. Added SSH keys (http://help.nitrous.io/ssh-windows/) using PuttyGen. I've tried creating the private key with a passphrase and without a passphrase with no success.
2. Setup connection on MySQL workbench. Used the SSH hostname from the Nitrous.IO box information panel as apse1.nitrousbox.com:10871, using 'action' as the username and no password.
3. Selected PPK file created using PuttyGen
4. Specified MySQL hostname as 127.0.0.1, port 3306 and user root with no password (works from local Nitrous.IO terminal)

Now when I test my connection I get the following error:

```
Could not connect the SSH Tunnel
Authentication error. Please check that your username and password are correct and try again.
Details (Original exception message):
Bad authentication type, the server is not accepting this type of authentication.
Allowed ones are:
['publickey']
```

Now I'm sure that this is the authentication type to be used since I specified the private key file. What could be wrong with this setup?

Answer (score 4):

The putty key files are not compatible with OpenSSH, so try converting the ppk file to OpenSSH (IIRC there's a tool in the putty package for that). Then also check that the remote SSH server accepts authentication with key files and not just via username/password.

Comment: Exporting the private key to OpenSSH worked for me. Thanks